# Right way to start a worker thread with Quarkus?

Tags: multithreading, background, startup, worker, quarkus

I am implementing a Quarkus server. On server start, a (never ending) background process should be started.

I know I can observe the start event with an `@ApplicationScoped`bean which implements:
`void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev)`.

But what is the best way to start a background process? Are there restrictions?
In J2EE one should not create Threads, but use `ManagedExecutorService` or an EJB with a `@Asynchronous` annotated method.

Is there something similar in Quarkus? I only found the scheduler annotations (which are nice, but I want to start a process only once at the beginning).

So can I just create threads? Or just put my infinite code in `void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev)` ?

Thank you

Comment: Answered this old question bc it does not have a proper answer yet have a lot of views. I figure you already solved your problem... :)

Answer (score 5):

As in EJB you should not do such things with a background process. Such processes that are "out of control" of the framework cause most of time very annoying problems.

The answer is: It depends on what you want to do in that job.

If you want to execute tasks on a regular base you could use timers.

If you want to use it as an asynchronous worker, you can use a message queue.

Both is most easily done with the [vert.x integration](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-messaging) into Quarkus.

Use @ConsumeEvent to create a queue, use

```
@Inject
EventBus bus;

bus.send("Example message");
```

to send messages.

Use @Scheduled to work on regular jobs, like in [this example](http://adambien.blog/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_quarkus_scheduler_timer).

If you need to permanently listen to some socket or file it is getting more difficult. Maybe the [websockets](https://quarkus.io/guides/websockets) will be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to start a worker thread is using Vertx#executeBlocking, like this:

```java
@Inject
Vertx vertx;

void foo() {
    vertx.<String>executeBlocking(promise -> {
        // This code will be executed in a worker thread
        System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
        promise.complete("Done");
    }, asyncResult -> {
        System.out.println(asyncResult.result()); // Done
    });
}
```

If it will be a long running thread maybe it's a good idea not to use the default worker thread pool and create a new one:

```java
...
@PostConstruct
void init() {
    this.executor = vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("my-worker", 10);
}
    
void foo() {
    executor.<String>executeBlocking(promise -> {
        ...
    }
}
```

Other way of doing this is using a [Verticle](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_verticles).